# Why is broadcasting done by aligning axes backwards

Tags: numpy, broadcasting

Numpy's broadcasting rules have bitten me once again and I'm starting to feel there may be a way of thinking about this
topic that I'm missing.

I'm often in situations as follows: the first axis of my arrays is reserved for something fixed, like the number of samples. The second axis could represent different independent variables of each sample, for some arrays, or it could be not existent when it feels natural that there only be one quantity attached to each sample in an array. For example, if the array is called `price`, I'd probably only use one axis, representing the price of each sample. On the other hand, a second axis is sometimes much more natural. For example, I could use a neural network to compute a quantity for each sample, and since neural networks can in general compute arbitrary multi valued functions, the library I use would in general return a 2d array and make the second axis singleton if I use it to compute a single dependent variable. I found this approach to use 2d arrays is also more amenable to future extensions of my code.

Long story short, I need to make decisions in various places of my codebase whether to store array as `(1000,)` or `(1000,1)`, and changes of requirements occasionally make it necessary to switch from one format to the other.
Usually, these arrays live alongside arrays with up to 4 axes, which further increases the pressure to sometimes introduce singleton second axis, and then have the third axis represent a consistent semantic quality for all arrays that use it.

The problem now occurs when I add my `(1000,)` or `(1000,1)` arrays, expecting to get `(1000,1)`, but get `(1000,1000)` because of implicit broadcasting.

I feel like this prevents giving semantic meaning to axes. Of course I could always use at least two axes, but that leads to the question where to stop: To be fail safe, continuing this logic, I'd have to always use arrays of at least 6 axes to represent everything.

I'm aware this is maybe not the best technically well defined question, but does anyone have a modus operandi that helps them avoid these kind of bugs?

Does anyone know the motivations of the numpy developers to align axes in reverse order for broadcasting? Was computational efficiency or another technical reason behind this, or a model of thinking that I don't understand?

Comment: Why do you need a (n,1) shape? If I'm going to add a size 1 dimension, a leading, outer one feels more natural. May I've worked with numpy too long, and have internalized the broadcasting rules.

Comment: @hpaulj hm, that sounds surprisingly simple, but I am surprised you'd call it natural. "First" means "leftmost" in most of the world, doesn't it? I'll see if your approach causes any other problems that I can't think of at the moment

Comment: One attractive feature of right aligning is that two C-contiguous arrays of same type with the same trailing dimensions have the same trailing strides. The same is not generally true for left aligning

Comment: The same problem occurs in my astronomy library Skyfield. I want to put the fixed dimension 3 up at the top so folks can use Python tuple unpacking `x,y,z = …` with the array, and put the variable dimension like time samples along the trailing axes. But then broadcasting winds up backwards, and tries to pair my math operations against the time axis rather than the coordinate axis.

Answer (score -1):

In MATLAB broadcasting, a jonny-come-lately to this game, expands trailing dimensions.  But there the trailing dimensions are outermost, that is `order='F'`.  And since everything starts as 2d, this expansion only occurs when one array is 3d (or larger).

https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/

explains, and gives a bit of history. My own history with the language is old enough, that the `ma_expanded = ma(ones(3,1),:)` style of expansion is familiar.  `octave` added broadcasting before MATLAB.

To avoid ambiguity, broadcasting expansion can only occur in one direction.  Expanding in the direction of the outermost dimension makes seems logical.

Compare (3,) expanded to (1,3) versus (3,1) - viewed as nested lists:

```
In [198]: np.array([1,2,3])                                                                                  
Out[198]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [199]: np.array([[1,2,3]])                                                                                
Out[199]: array([[1, 2, 3]])
In [200]: (np.array([[1,2,3]]).T).tolist()                                                                   
Out[200]: [[1], [2], [3]]
```

I don't know if there are significant implementation advantages.  With the striding mechanism, adding a new dimension anywhere is easy.  Just change the `shape` and `strides`, adding a `0` for the dimension that needs to be 'replicated'.

```
In [203]: np.broadcast_arrays(np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([[1],[2],[3]]),np.ones((3,3)))                      
Out[203]: 
[array([[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]]), array([[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3]]), array([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]])]
In [204]: [x.strides for x in _]                                                                             
Out[204]: [(0, 8), (8, 0), (24, 8)]
```